# What happens if the router is ddosed?

Tags: router, ip, denial-of-service

I don't know what happens if a router gets DDOS'ed? Does it brick it self or it just disables its ip? And if the ip disables its just easy fix by power cycling the router to get a new ip and getting it back to normal state.

Comment: In general, a router that is receiving too much traffic, will attempt to buffer the incoming data, and use flow control mechanisms to attempt to ask the sender to back off. It will just keep doing that to the extent that it can, until the traffic abides, or until the unit crashes. Unless you have a very sophisticated device, there is nothing else possible. As a general rule, you defeat DDOS attacks upstream at the bandwidth provider. smaller scale DOS attacks can be mitigated by bucket filtering, if they are attacking a state table, but DDOS is generally too much for the firewall to handle.

Answer (score 2):

Each incoming packet on any network device consumes resources.  What happens when those resources run out depend heavily on the router, whether the packets are part of a connection the router is also tracking (which causes the router to use more resources), and the software it's running.

The most low-level protocol of the internet, the IP protocol, which just about every other Internet-based communication is based off of these days, is unreliable by design and specification.

What this means is that if a device cannot process an IP packet, completely "dropping it" or ignoring it is an option.  Well engineered router software and hardware will do this when it is overloaded and not crash.

So if an overloaded router has no memory or other resources to temporarily buffer/process an incoming packet, it will likely simply ignore it.

So the question is, what will the other side do when it never "hears back" from the communication.

Some communication is explicitly one-way, so really the other side won't even know anything was dropped.  Syslog is an example of a one-way type of communication.

Dropped packets in TCP exchanges will cause timeouts, which will cause retransmissions and eventually narrowing down the TCP "window" or number of packets that can be "in-flight" without acknowledgement.  Overall this will cause anything TCP-based (like HTTP, etc.) to slow down if only some packets are getting through, and if the DDOS is completely consuming all the router's resources, it will slow down then stop, and think there is nothing on the other side.  If the other side of a TCP connection does not close it, then the only way TCP can figure out if the other side is dead is by letting a timeout expire.

Now, badly engineered router software may stall or crash if incoming traffic has no resources.  Or badly/cheaply/consumer-level engineered devices may do most of the work in software, which consumes CPU resources, and can easily get overloaded to the point where you cannot log into them if they are processing too much traffic.  You would have to have some pretty bad hardware/software on a router where it would get bricked if overloaded with traffic, and I'm sure there are some dirt-cheap routers that are like that.

Commercial gear does much of this in hardware and the CPU is mostly just processing commands.

If you are in the same situation as many businesses, you have a static or permanently assigned IP and cannot just "get a new IP" by making your router request a new one - your router is simply set to the IP your ISP assigned you.

Home users will have dynamic IPs and if your ISP gives you a new IP when your router asks for it, then yes, the DDOS will stop if they are only attacking that one IP.

Comment: You have to understand a DDOS is about saturating your incoming connection, not breaking through a barrier.  Firewalls will prevent traffic from getting past a certain point in your network but it's still coming into your network in the first place, and hence still denying service to/from you.